# Why does my floating div push around other divs?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has a table which has a google map.

I want to place a info box within the google map external to the map, just floating on top

But I can't seem to get it right, the info div just pushes around the google map despite being on top of the map...

CSS

```
.google_map {
    height: 270px;
    width: 100%;
 }

    #flightMapInfo {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        z-index: 100;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        top: 30px;
        left: 50px;
        background:#5a85a5;
        padding: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    }


div.tabContent {
    border: 1px solid #c9c3ba;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #f1f0ee;
    min-height: 300px;
}


.tableLeft {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    border-right: dotted 2px black;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="mapBlock tabContent">
        <div id="flightMapInfo">WHARGL</div>
        <table class="tableLeft">
            <tr><td><div id="flightMap" class="google_map"></div>
               </table></td></tr></div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wanted to comment on @scunliffe's answers, but this is rather lengthy.

`Float` says to browser, that rather than normal behaviour, `div`should be either left or right and the rest of content should flow around (think: Images in *.doc).

Your problem is, that you confuse english '**float**' [*To remain suspended within or on the surface of a fluid without sinking*] with css' '**float**' [*stay to 'left' or 'right' border and flow rest of website content around*]

What you want to do is take the div out of normal flow of webpage (thus: `position:absolute`) position it.

Hint:
`absolute` is relative to 0;0 of first found ancestor, which is `relative` or `absolute`.   `Relative`is relative to 0;0 of what would be position in normal flow.

Relative divs* act as if they were on their original place , they are just rendered shifted. Absolute divs* are taken out of flow of website and position accordingly to hint above.

- - by div, I mean any styled tag

I apologize if you know all this and just can't make it work.

**EDIT**
In `position:absolute;` this means first found ancestor:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="innerWrapper">
      <div id="content">
```

and two `CSS` cases:

1.

```
#content { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px; }
```

2.

```
#innerWrapper { positon: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px; }
#content { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px; }
```

In case one, since nether `#wrapper` nor `#innerWrapper` have set position, first `absolute` or `relative` ancestor in tree is body, thus positioning of 10px;20px is made from 0;0 of body (read: viewport) - `#content` is at 10;20 of window.

In case two, #innerWrapper is set `absolute`, thus making 200;200 of *window* a point, which is understood as 0;0 when positioning `#content`. Therefore (absolute ancestor found), `content` will be at 210;220 of window

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3dq6V/

Comment: That is a lot of interesting info, detailed enough to 'make sense' to me (No magic usage here). However, while I understand both my mistake with float and position, I'm still testing my way forward with the positioning and inheritance that it seems to involve.

Comment: I appreciate not being specific on what to actually do, while yet providing insight in the situation. After a bit of pondering and a quick insight I realized that as the map is positioned inside the flow and should keep flow, it didn't need a position defined, but the div I'm trying to place needs a position based on nearest ancestor which has one - It could simply be set to relative, keeping it in line while becoming a useful ancestor. Correct me if I'm wrong ;P

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `position:absolute;` not `float:xxx`.

Float just indicates that it will "flow" with the other elements on the screen... you want it to float above the other content and not be constrained by it, thus you want absolute positioning.

Comment: position absolute will make it relevant to the window in itself, I need it to be placed based on the div it's in

Comment: thanks @Adam Kiss - you're right about the confusion over wording... it isn't very clear.  I think to pull off the final idea @Meke is after, the info box needs to be "absolute" but have the left/top coordinates adjusted (in JavaScript) to be "relative" to the map's coordinates.